# PropertySheetView in netbeans application development

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I am creating a application using Netbeans Appication development.

i have created a API and a lookup that checks for all the implementation and displays them to a Jlist placed inside a TopComponent.

```
public interface DemoAPI {
public String getType();
public String getName();
}
```

used

```
Lookup.Result<DemoAPI> DemoResult;
DemoResult=Lookup.getDefault().lookupResult(DemoAPI.class);

public void resultChanged(LookupEvent ev) {
        for (DemoAPI demo : DemoResult.allInstances()) {
        //Added the demo to Jlist using demo.getName() as display Name
    }
    }
```

for getting all the implementation of DemoAPI and Displaying in ListBox.

How can i Display the properties (Type and Name) in the propertySheetView for the corresponding selected Jlist Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you most certainly need to use Nodes combined with an ExplorerManager and a corresponding view, replacing your JList.

[This tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nodesapi2.html) explains the basics of nodes and using them with an ExplorerManager and all kind of different views. In your created nodes you would override the `getSheed()`-Method and create your PropertySheet there.

The [Netbeans Developer FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ) is a nice place which descripes a lot of the usual tasks when developing an application. [Nodes and Explorer](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ#Nodes_and_Explorer) should tell you a lot about Nodes, ExplorerManagers and the several Views. [Properties and PropertySheets](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ#Properties_and_PropertySheet) has some nice extra info regarding PropertySheets.